# Typo3 Rich Snippets with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have not been successful to implement rich snippets in my typo3 site. Basically I have tried to wrap the html tag and include meta snippets to no avail but a chain of site errors.

```html
page.meta.itemprop.name = name
page.meta.itemprop.description = description 
page.meta.itemprop.image = http://www.example.com/img/01.png
```

The html code is the following

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<meta itemprop="name" content="name">
<meta itemprop="description" content="description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/image.png">
```

What typoscript should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked out for me.

```html
config.htmlTag_stdWrap {
    setContentToCurrent = 1
    cObject = COA
    cObject {
        1 = TEXT
        1.value = itemscope 
        1.noTrimWrap = | | |
        2 = TEXT
        2.value = itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"
        2.noTrimWrap = | | |
  3 = TEXT
        3.value = lang="en"
        wrap = <html | >
    }
}
page {
  headerData {
    4 = TEXT
    4.value (
<meta itemprop="name" content="Your site Name">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Your site description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/img/01.png">
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea of how to add dynamic name and description within the wrap, through typoscript?<meta itemprop="name" content="Your site Name">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Your site description">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.example.com/img/01.png">

Comment: Yes, you can use stdWrap data or dataWrap to insert values from the current page context.

Comment: pgampe thanks, can you give me an example of the code structure please

Comment: `stdWrap.data` and `stdWrap.dataWrap` have the `getText` data type. Please consult the manual for plenty examples: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html